# What are alternative ICs for MC33274?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I'm using MPX2100dp pressure sensor for my project. I learnt that using MC33274 quad opamp can be used for making instrumentation amplifier. This IC is not available in local stores where I live. So I want alternative IC for this. Any suggestion for instrumentation amplifier is welcomed.

Comment: Asking for shopping recommendations is off topic. This question will probably be closed. That being said, just go to an electronics distributed site like farnell or digikey and use their search tool to find one that matches what you want

Answer (score 1):

Normally this question would be closed because seeking product recommendations is off topic here. I am going to provide an answer for a suitable part. Then I am going to point out a number of reasons why these types of questions typically get closed.

You could try the LT1127 from Analog Devices (formerly Linear Technology). This part has almost all its key features at specs that are better than the MC33274. You can preview its [data sheet from the Analog Devices web site](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1126_27fa.pdf).

Now for the list of reasons this question would usually be closed so you can see just why this is cannot generally be supported.

1. You provided zero evidence that you made any attempt to find a part replacement by searching. *(If you had found a part it would have been a legitimate question to ask for help in comparing certain part specs against your design requirements).*
2. You gave no design details of your project and what your actual design requirements are. *(There is probably no design that would require every spec offered by a given product).*
3. We have no idea what parts are available to you in your local market.
4. You have provided no selection parameters that are important to you (price, package, performance, ...) so how can anyone else ever begin to read your mind.
5. Any recommendation made to you would be only for you. *(The questions at this site, that are on topic, are generally expected to be of interest to a general international audience).*